# Finding and editing an object in a list if I have the tag of that object from a selected treeview node

Tags: c#, winforms, list, treeview

I currently have working `new` and `delete` functions for my application, but I am trying to figure out how to implement an `edit` on the selected node in my treeview. At the moment I can change the text of the node, but that isn't changing the actual name stored in the object of the list. How would one do this? Here is the code that I have so far:

```
    private void OnGroupEditClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GroupForm groupForm = new GroupForm();
        if (groupForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        _treeViewGroups.SelectedNode.Text = groupForm.Group.Name;
    }
```

If it helps, here is how I'm implementing `new` and `delete`:

```
    private void OnGroupNewClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GroupForm groupForm = new GroupForm();
        if (groupForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        Group group = groupForm.Group;
        KeyPassManager.addGroup(group);

        TreeNode node = _treeViewGroups.Nodes.Add(group.Name);
        _treeViewGroups.SelectedNode = node;
        node.Tag = group;
    }

    private void OnGroupDeleteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteConfirmation deleteConfirmation = new DeleteConfirmation();

        if (deleteConfirmation.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        Group group = (Group)_treeViewGroups.SelectedNode.Tag;

        KeyPassManager.removeGroup(group);
        _treeViewGroups.Nodes.Remove(_treeViewGroups.SelectedNode);
    }
```

Comment: @steve wouldn't I have to pass the newly instantiated Group with the new group name back into the list of groups to be found, then set the name of the corresponding element in that list to the name of the Group I passed into it? I'm not sure how changing a new instantiate of an object would change that object within a list. Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the GroupForm for editing you should pass the Group variable extracted from the Tag property of the SelectedNode through the form constructor. Inside the Group form you could directly edit it and when you return the instance has already been updated.

```
private void OnGroupEditClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(_treeViewGroups.SelectedNode != null)
    {
        // Extract the instance of the Group to edit
        Group grp = _treeViewGroups.SelectedNode.Tag as Group;

        // Pass the instance at the GroupForm 
        GroupForm groupForm = new GroupForm(grp);
        if (groupForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;
        _treeViewGroups.SelectedNode.Text = groupForm.Group.Name;
    }
}
```

Inside the GroupForm dialog you receive the instance passed and save it in a global variable in this way

```
public class GroupForm: Form
{
   private Group _groupInEdit = null;

   public Group Group
   {
       get { return _groupInEdit; }
   }

   public GroupForm(Group grp = null)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       _groupInEdit = grp;
   }
   private void GroupForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if(_grpInEdit != null)
       {
           ... initialize controls with using values from the 
           ... instance passed through the constructor
       }
   }
   private void cmdOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // If the global is null then we have been called from 
       // the OnGroupNewClick code so we need to create the Group here
       if(_grpInEdit == null)
          _grpInEdit = new Group();

       _grpInEdit.Name = ... name from your textbox...
       ... other values
   }
}
```

Added a bit of checking on the usage of your TreeView nodes, probably not needed but....

Comment: Thanks for switching this over from a comment to an answer. I posted a little response to your original comment if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: Yes, I have read your comment and understand better your problem. Now I have changed the answer a lot... refresh the page

Comment: thanks for your detailed response. Would editing the group using this actually edit the values in the related entry in my list of groups as well though?

Comment: In the Tag properties of the various nodes you store the references to the memory addresses where each Group instance is stored.  Passing a Tag value (alias the Group reference) you allow your form to 'see' the original Group instance. Thus the editing happens on the same instance whose reference is stored in the Tag. Yes it changes the property of the Group instance stored in the treeview node tags. Of course, you still need to set the property Text of the Node clicked to the same value of the Group.Name